# How to increase the performance of database schema creation?

Tags: mysql, database

For our testing environment, I need to setup und tear down a database multiple times (each test should run independently of any other).

The process is the following:

- Create database schema and insert necessary data
- Run test 1
- Remove all tables in database
- Create database schema and insert necessary data
- Run test 2
- Remove all tables in database
- ...

The schema and data are the same for each test in the test case.

Basically, this works. The big problem is, that the creation and clearing of the database takes a lot of time. Is there a possibility to improve the performance of mysql for the creation of tables and the insertion of data? Or can you think of a different process for the tests?

Thank for you your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increase the performance of a Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007575/how-to-increase-the-performance-of-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

**Optimize the logical design**

The logical level is about the structure of the query and tables themselves. Try to maximize this first. The goal is to access as few data as possible at the logical level.

- Have the most efficient SQL queries
- Design a logical schema that support the application's need (e.g. type of the columns, etc.)
- Design trade-off to support some use case better than other
- Relational constraints
- Normalization

**Optimize the physical design**

The physical level deals with non-logical consideration, such as type of indexes, parameters of the tables, etc. Goal is to optimize the IO which is always the bottleneck. Tune each table to fit it's need. Small table can be loaded permanently loaded in the DBMS cache, table with low write rate can have different settings than table with high update rate to take less disk spaces, etc. Depending on the queries, different index can be used, etc. You can denormalized data transparently with materialized views, etc.

- Tables paremeters (allocation size, etc.)
- Indexes (combined, types, etc.)
- System-wide parameters (cache size, etc.)
- Partitioning
- Denormalization

Try first to improve the logical design, then the physical design. (The boundary between both is however vague, so we can argue about my categorization).

**Optimize the maintenance**

Database must be operated correctly to stay as efficient as possible. This include a few mainteanance taks that can have impact on the perofrmance, e.g.

- Keep statistics up to date
- Re-sequence critical tables periodically
- Disk maintenance
- All the system stuff to have a server that rocks

**source from:[How to increase the performance of a Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007575/how-to-increase-the-performance-of-a-database)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can write all your need operations into an script using shell、perl or python(init_db).
The first use, you can create、 insert and delete manually，then dump both the schema and data .
You can choose bulk insert and drop table for deleting data to improve the total performance.
Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DROP TABLE + CREATE TABLE, just do TRUNCATE TABLE.  This may, or may not, be faster; give it a try.

If you are INSERTing multiple rows each time, then either batch them (all rows in one INSERT), or use LOAD DATA.  Either of these is much faster than row-by-row INSERTs.

Also fast...  If you have the initial data in another table (which you could keep permanently), then do

```
CREATE TABLE test SELECT * FROM perm_table;
... (run tests using `test`)
DROP TABLE test;
```